# is there is any way to don't compute a computed field till another field change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11, erp

if i upgraded my module to the last version which contains this method all prices changes to 0 ?
what shall i do to pervent price from changes till i added any recoerd in average field .. ??

i add computed field on product template to compute average of some items and display it 
also i added a compute method on list_price field to computed it with the average above and cost price .

```
@api.one
@api.depends('item.pro', 'drc.pro', 'dsc.pro', 'org.pro', 'car.pro', 'model.pro', 'year.pro')
def update_bar(self):
        list=[self.item.pro, self.drc.pro, self.dsc.pro, self.org.pro, self.car.pro, self.model.pro, self.year.pro]
        list = [float(x) for x in list if x is not False]
        try:
            self.pro =float(sum(list) / len(list))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            if self.pro == float("inf") or self.pro == float("-inf") :
                return float('nan')  # or x or return whatever makes sense
            pass

@api.one
@api.depends('pro')
def testprice(self):
    if self.pro != 0 :
        for template in self:
            template.list_price = float(((self.pro + self.ex_pro) * self.standard_price / 100) + self.standard_price)

list_price = fields.Float(string="Price", required=False,compute=testprice)
pro = fields.Float(string="profit mergin", required=False,compute=update_bar,)
ex_pro = fields.Float(string="Extra profit", required=False,placeholder= "%" )
```

Comment: I don't think it will work like that, but post here, if you got any answer.

Comment: the field declarations are wrong. udpate question with the correct code. Compute field is not defining as you shown above.

Comment: what is wrong ??